# Excel, VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that has data formatted as follows:

[image]

I want to create a vlookup or an index match where I can type the Date, and category(MIB, DAX, CAC, etc.) in 2 different cells and it will pull the correct open value.
ie.  In adjacent cells I type 2016-03-08, then CAC, it should return 4405.1602.

I have had trouble creating this because of the way the data is formatted (I cant format any other way, it is coming in live from a third party source), as well because the dates do not always line up.

I have tried creating a seperate VLOOKUP for each category, B3:C13 for MIB, D3:E13 for DAX, but this is extremely time consuming as the actual spreadsheet goes much further and contains much more data than the sample I have given here, so I am hoping there is a formula I can use to avoid this.

```
$FTSEMIB-MIL            $DAX-XET            $PX1-EEB            $UKX-FTSE       
Date    Open    Last    Date    Open    Last    Date    Open    Last    Date    Open    Last
2016-03-18  18704.369   18611.34    2016-03-18  9905.6699   9950.8  2016-03-18  4452.04 4462.51 2016-03-18  6201.1201   6189.64
2016-03-17  18921.43    18608.029   2016-03-17  10051.69    9892.2002   2016-03-17  4501.6802   4442.8901   2016-03-17  6175.4902   6201.1201
2016-03-16  18820.789   18731.75    2016-03-16  9971.04 9983.4102   2016-03-16  4486.7002   4463    2016-03-16  6139.9702   6175.4902
2016-03-15  18891.721   18765.369   2016-03-15  9941.46 9933.8496   2016-03-15  4474.2598   4472.6299   2016-03-15  6174.5698   6139.9702
2016-03-14  19125.109   18981.77    2016-03-14  9948.21 9990.2598   2016-03-14  4501.8101   4506.5898   2016-03-14  6139.79 6174.5698
2016-03-11  18488.82    18987.75    2016-03-11  9672.0498   9831.1299   2016-03-11  4430.2402   4492.79 2016-03-11  6036.7002   6139.79
2016-03-10  18229.24    18118.23    2016-03-10  9697.6396   9498.1504   2016-03-10  4432.5601   4350.3501   2016-03-10  6146.3198   6036.7002
2016-03-09  17982.369   18208.92    2016-03-09  9700.1602   9723.0898   2016-03-09  4405.9502   4425.6499   2016-03-09  6125.4399   6146.3198
2016-03-08  17906.02    18017.561   2016-03-08  9688.4697   9692.8203   2016-03-08  4405.1602   4404.02 2016-03-08  6182.3999   6125.4399
2016-03-07  18195.6 18059.27    2016-03-07  9764.0801   9778.9297   2016-03-07  4436.3701   4442.29 2016-03-07  6199.4302   6182.3999
2016-03-04  18415.359   18278.98    2016-03-04  9800.8604   9824.1699   2016-03-04  4437.8198   4456.6201   2016-03-04  6130.46 6199.4302
2016-03-03  18217.98    18348.5 2016-03-03  9807.0596   9751.9199   2016-03-03  4430.8999   4416.0801   2016-03-03  6147.0601   6130.46
2016-03-02  18143.221   18206.41    2016-03-02  9780.8398   9776.6201   2016-03-02  4428.9502   4424.8901   2016-03-02  6152.8799   6147.0601
2016-03-01  17557.23    18011.91    2016-03-01  9482.6602   9717.1602   2016-03-01  4343.9302   4406.8398   2016-03-01  6097.0898   6152.8799
2016-02-29  17341.74    17623.07    2016-02-29  9424.9297   9495.4004   2016-02-29  4275.8398   4353.5498   2016-02-29  6096.0098   6097.0898
2016-02-26  17299.029   17483.76    2016-02-26  9454.5195   9513.2998   2016-02-26  4297.8701   4314.5698   2016-02-26  6012.8101   6096.0098
2016-02-25  16939.52    17104.539   2016-02-25  9277.0195   9331.4805   2016-02-25  4219.7998   4248.4502   2016-02-25  5867.1802   6012.8101
2016-02-24  17157.73    16719.359   2016-02-24  9396.4805   9167.7998   2016-02-24  4232.48 4155.3398   2016-02-24  5962.3101   5867.1802
2016-02-23  17340.23    17163.461   2016-02-23  9503.1201   9416.7695   2016-02-23  4272.2202   4238.4199   2016-02-23  6037.73 5962.3101
2016-02-22  17127.65    17504.58    2016-02-22  9481.3701   9573.5898   2016-02-22  4260.6201   4298.7002   2016-02-22  5950.23 6037.73
2016-02-19  17024.76    16909.561   2016-02-19  9420.5098   9388.0498   2016-02-19  4232.2202   4223.04 2016-02-19  5971.9502   5950.23
```

Comment: Try an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair. If you require more help, put some sample data into the question that doesn't require retyping. See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: I tried putting the data in the question instead of the picture but the formatting kept screwing up. I new to this site, is there a way I can copy and paste from excel but keep the formatting?

I tried index match with array formulas but i couldnt get it to work because of the multiple criteria (Date, Category, Open) as well as that the dates it looked for werent always in the left most column but in the middle of the table depending on the category selected.

Comment: There is Help and Advanced Help in the question editor. What you are looking for is to paste hte data in then select it and tap Ctrl+K. If you tried a solution and couldn't get it to work then post your attempt; you would be surprised at the amount of information that even a failed formula discloses that was not included in the narrative.

Comment: What about `=VLOOKUP(A2,OFFSET(A:B,0,MATCH(A1,3:3,0)-1),2,0)` where A1 is the category and A2 is the date?

Comment: While you are getting that sample data together, consider a combination of CAC and 2016-03-12. While 2016-03-12 does not exist in the CAC dates, your dates are in descending order so an approximate lookup could be made with MATCH for 2016-03-14 but not VLOOKUP. Is that important?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(A2,OFFSET(A:B,0,MATCH(A1,3:3,0)-1),2,0) works perfectly, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use a conventional [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) with the date as the *lookup_value*. Select and shape the *table_array* parameter from a larger block of data using an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair matching the category across row 4.

In E15 as a standard formula,

```
=VLOOKUP(D15, INDEX($B$6:$H$13, 0, MATCH(C15, B$4:H$4, 0)):INDEX($C$6:$I$13, 0, MATCH(C15, B$4:H$4, 0)), 2, FALSE)
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: vlookup_index_match]